# Mysql service not starting in WAMP

Tags: mysql, wamp

I just reinstalled WAMP in my pc which runs Windows 7. When I try to start WAMP then it is orange and not green. So I did exactly the steps of [this](http://awesomesteps.wordpress.com/2012/10/06/wamp-server-turned-orange-after-installation/) tutorial. But again the WAMP is orange. There is no problem with apache because it is correctly in port 80. Then I went to  WAMP->Mysql-> Service and when I click start/Resume Service then nothing happens. What is the problem? I checked my error log and I have this

```
2013-07-31 19:30:21 1776 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
2013-07-31 19:30:21 c4c InnoDB: Warning: Using innodb_additional_mem_pool_size is DEPRECATED. This option may be removed in future releases, together with the option innodb_use_sys_malloc and with the InnoDB's internal memory allocator.
2013-07-31 19:30:21 1776 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
2013-07-31 19:30:21 1776 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2013-07-31 19:30:21 1776 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
2013-07-31 19:30:21 1776 [Note] InnoDB: Not using CPU crc32 instructions
2013-07-31 19:30:21 1776 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 101.0M
2013-07-31 19:30:21 1776 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2013-07-31 19:30:22 1776 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
2013-07-31 19:30:22 1776 [Warning] InnoDB: Resizing redo log from 2*3072 to 2*1664 pages, LSN=1625977
2013-07-31 19:30:22 1776 [Warning] InnoDB: Starting to delete and rewrite log files.
2013-07-31 19:30:22 1776 [Note] InnoDB: Setting log file .\ib_logfile101 size to 26 MB
2013-07-31 19:30:24 1776 [Note] InnoDB: Setting log file .\ib_logfile1 size to 26 MB
2013-07-31 19:30:26 1776 [Note] InnoDB: Renaming log file .\ib_logfile101 to .\ib_logfile0
2013-07-31 19:30:26 1776 [Warning] InnoDB: New log files created, LSN=1625977
2013-07-31 19:30:26 1776 [Note] InnoDB: 128 rollback segment(s) are active.
2013-07-31 19:30:26 1776 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2013-07-31 19:30:26 1776 [Note] InnoDB: 5.6.12 started; log sequence number 1625977
2013-07-31 19:30:26 1776 [ERROR] wampmysqld: unknown variable 'table_cache=256'
2013-07-31 19:30:26 1776 [ERROR] Aborting
```

So WAMP cannot start Mysql. What else I have to check?

Comment: Is there a line in your my.ini that has table_cache=256? Try table_open_cache: http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?11,580232,580392#msg-580392

Comment: @SarahKemp There is no table_cache=256? in my.ini file

Comment: I should have put that in code marks. Did you look for `table_cache=256` or `table_cache=256?` - I meant the question mark to be part of the sentence, not the code.

Comment: finally I removed the last version of WAMP 2.4 and I installed the previous one WAMP 2.2 and it works fine without any problem and now is is green...I do not know what is the problem with the last version...

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the parameter `innodb_additional_mem_pool_size` from your my.ini.

Comment: @VishalKumarSahu This is a 4 year old question and answer. Things have changed in MySQL in 4 years. I suggest you ask a question stating your current versions and also your current problem.

Comment: Okay! I guess new versions have different settings and options.